# How to edit the database with pgAdmin4 to connect Heroku

Tags: heroku, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create the database on pgAdmin4 to connect to my heroku application. But I cannot edit SQL file.

1. How to edit the SQL file, I want to add the data with `.sql` file
2. How to create new database
3. How to change heroku database credentials

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- How to edit the SQL file, I want to add the data with .sql file

You can use Import/Export tool to add the data from SQL file.
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/import_export_data.html

- How to create new database

There is an option to create new database in pgAdmin4.
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/database_dialog.html

- How to change heroku database credentials

You can change the database password from pgAdmin4 itself
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/change_password_dialog.html